# Node.js: Create a Web Hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, webhooks

What's the easiest way of creating a Web Hook in Node.js? (POST to a URL).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: ...
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});
```

From the [http.request](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.6/api/all.html#http.request) docs.

Basically you can request with an opinions hash to a host/port + path with a method. Then handle the response from that server.

Comment: I believe he is trying to create an HTTP server, not a client.

Comment: Thanks. I do just that but when I create the JSON string, the value is passed with errors, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693247/node-js-create-json-and-post-to-postbin

Comment: @igorw He wants to POST to an URL in node.

Answer (score 3):

From the Node.js homepage:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

You can access the req object to get at the data.

For a more high level approach, check out [express.js](http://expressjs.com/).

You can do things like:

```
var app = express.createServer();

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Do I need a server or a client? I don't quite understand why I need to create a server to POST. Thanks

Comment: @donald you do not. You need a server to handle incoming data. you want to post data to another server so this answer is not relevant.

Comment: Original question was ambiguous. I thought he was asking how to receive an HTTP POST.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the node.js module [restler](https://github.com/danwrong/restler).

```
rest.post('http://user:pass@service.com/action', {
    data: { id: 334 },
}).on('complete', function(data, response) {
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        // you can get at the raw response like this...
    }
});
```